# How can install a driver for touchpad of laptop ASUS x53u?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, asus

I installed ubuntu 12.04, I switched windows 7 for this. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu is shipped by default with this driver 
the package for that is called "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics"

if it is not present:
for KDE use muon to install it

or from command line:
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have had a lot of issues with the touchpad. This helped to fix my inability to right-click with the right button of the touchpad:

https://superuser.com/questions/61958...rking-in-linux

Now my biggest problem is that I have to really bang on the touchpad to make it click. I don't mean the buttons but the touchpad area itself is not sensitive AT ALL in spite of having the sensitivity cranked up in the system tools/mouse and touchpad.

Also sometimes even when I bang on it hard, it is only the second or third click that is recognized, not the first. This makes the click feature of the touchpad almost worthless.

I have the speed and acceleration turned all the way up but I would like the cursor to move faster, accelerate faster, and move more with each swipe on the touchpad since I have a big screen to cover (17inch).

Any ideas? Also the touchpad does not completely turn off while typing. Or it doesn't turn off long enough. The cursor wobbles all over as I type.

So, yeah, this touchpad is a nightmare with the G750 in Ubuntu.

Another thing is the video card. When I scroll, I see a wonky line in the middle of the screen, going horizontally. I tried using the built-in method to update the video driver, but it didn't help even though it installed the driver.

I should mention too that using the touchpad I can't select multiple files in a series using either shift-click or ctrl-click. This is really frustrating!

Any help for these problems would be much, much appreciated.